# Unable to read data from gpsfake

Tags: bash, tcp, gpsd

I saved the following NMEA-messages to the file `messages.txt`:

```
$GPRMC,131131.00,A,5956.4298,N,03015.4464,E,00.00,310.5,130123,,,D*53
$GPRMC,131132.00,A,5956.4298,N,03015.4464,E,00.01,097.3,130123,,,D*5B
$GNGSA,A,3,25,01,06,12,17,19,24,32,,,,,01.2,00.6,01.0*12
$GNGSA,A,3,66,86,77,76,75,85,67,68,84,,,,01.2,00.6,01.0*1B
$GPRMC,131133.00,A,5956.4298,N,03015.4464,E,00.00,181.5,130123,,,D*5B
$GNGSA,A,3,25,01,06,12,17,19,24,32,,,,,01.2,00.6,01.0*12
$GNGSA,A,3,66,86,77,76,75,85,67,68,84,,,,01.2,00.6,01.0*1B
$GPGNS,131134.00,,,,,,08,,,,02.2,0005*75
$GLGNS,131134.00,,,,,,09,,,,07.0,0005*6F
```

and executed:

```
gpsfake messages.txt
```

After that the output of the command:

```
lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

was

```
...
gpsd      71964  den    4u  IPv4 310168      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2947 (LISTEN)
gpsd      71964  den    5u  IPv6 310169      0t0  TCP [::1]:2947 (LISTEN)
...
```

When I tried to read the messages:

```
cat </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/2947
```

The output contained only:

```
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.22","rev":"3.22","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14}
```

Tried to read them with gpspipe but its output didn't contain gps data either:

```
sudo gpspipe -n 10 -w
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.22","rev":"3.22","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14}
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false}
```

After execution of the command above the output of gpsfake changed to:

```
Processing messages.txt
gpsfake: log cycle of messages.txt begins.
...
gpsd:ERROR: SER: device open of /dev/pts/12 failed: Permission denied - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: SER: read-only device open of /dev/pts/12 failed: Permission denied
gpsd:ERROR: /dev/pts/12: device activation failed, freeing device.
```

How to read data from `gpsfake` properly?